# What statistical test is performed by summary(glht(model, linfct=mcp(factor="Tukey")), test=adjusted(type="none"))?

Tags: r, multiple-comparisons, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I have data that I have fit using lme with the following structure (`Subject` is implemented as a random effect in order to account for multiple paired comparisons):

```
model <- lme(values ~ factor, data=mydata.df, random=~1|Subject, 
             na.action=na.omit, contrasts=c("contr.sum","contr. poly"))
```

`anova(model)` performs an F test and reports the significance of the relationship between `values` and `factor`. Then I use `glht` to do posthoc comparisons among the levels of `factor`. I don't want `summary` to apply a correction for multiple comparisons, I just want the raw p-values, because later I pool all the raw p-values for a larger set of related models and hypotheses, and perform a false discovery rate (FDR) correction.

I'm having trouble navigating the [documentation](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/multcomp/docs/glht) to determine exactly what statistical test is being performed by `glht`. Is it performing univariate t-tests between two factor levels at a time, without considering pooled variance across all levels, or is it in fact considering the full variance of the model (that's what I want it to do)? Actually, it reports z values, not t values, so does that imply that it is referring to the population variance? Is the test, then, simply called a "z-test"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does individual $z$ tests (asymptotic $t$ tests, since df are not available) for each comparison. It uses the results of `vcov` to obtain standard errors for each comparison. These use the model error, not individual parts of the dataset.

You can specify `type="fdr"` directly though, as `glht` can support all the methods in `p.adjust.methods`.

Comment: Thank you. I don't want to apply the fdr correction "locally" because I have more comparisons to do across other factors, and prefer to correct all the p-values "globally". So, can you confirm for me that z-tests are indeed comparing the means and variances of two levels to the pooled variance across all levels?

Comment: Yes. That is what I was trying to say.